# Background Image in CSS is not being displayed

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I want to display a background for the body of my webpage and I tried to use the background-image directly from CSS but the image is not being displayed, I checked and verified the extension and paths of the Image but it still isn't displayed. the following is my code what changes should I apply.

```
.navigation {
background-image: url('Images/Logo.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: cover; 
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: try '/Images/Logo.png'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hllo!
You can try this if your css file is in separately folder:
background-image: url('../Images/Logo.png');